# SQL score rank Self join, COUNT

Tags: sql

Base on a table Scores with column Score, write the query to get score and rank.

Here is the code:

```
    SELECT Scores.Score, Q2.Rank 
        FROM(
            Scores
            LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT Scores.Score AS Dis_score,
COUNT(DISTINCT(Scores.Score) AS Rank FROM Scores)AS Q2 
    ON Scores.Score = Q2.Dis_score)   
        ORDER BY Scores.Score DESC;

Input:  {"headers": {"Scores": ["Id", "Score"]}, "rows": {"Scores": [[1, 0.00], [2, 0.00], [3, 0.01]]}}
Output: {"headers": ["Score", "Rank"], "values": [[0.01, null], [0.00, 2], [0.00, 2]]}
Expected:   {"headers": ["Score", "Rank"], "values": [[0.01, 1], [0.00, 2], [0.00, 2]]}
```

When it comes to the case above, why 0.01 returns COUNT() with null???

Comment: where's the sample table?

Comment: I think you are missing a parentheses, but just the same, what is the output of: `SELECT DISTINCT Scores.Score AS Dis_score,
COUNT(DISTINCT(Scores.Score)) AS Rank FROM Scores`

Comment: @JNevill, it should return all scores, not only the distinct

Comment: Its your sql from your subquery. Just curious what it returns before your main query gets ahold of it.

Comment: @JNevill Can you please give me the whole script? I can't follow you here

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a subquery:

```
SELECT s.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s2.score)
        FROM scores s2
        WHERE s2.score <= s.score
       ) as rank
FROM Scores s;
```

It is unclear from your question whether you want `<=` or `>=`.

Comment: Could you please explain s2.socre <= s.score? How to use that?

Comment: Not exactly <= or >= because the same score has the same rank, for example, [2,2,1]  with rank [1,1,3]

Comment: @DreamTutor . . . Without sample data and desired results, it is unclear what you mean by "rank" in the question.